# What happens when a Activity is finished provided an Animation is not stopped in that Activity?

Tags: android, animation

If I finish an `Activity` on `onBAckPressed` method without stopping an 
animation what will be the affect in the memory? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: animation will also get terminated. Nothin unusual happens in memory in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, Android provides specific amount of Memory for each Application. That's why we see VM Budget out of memory error sometimes, if we are doing something with large image size. In your case if your animation is using enough memory, then on back pressed Activity will terminate along with all child views, it means your animation will also be terminated. And your application can use that space which is occupying by your animation (If It is related to image, otherwise there will be minimal effect on the memory).